# Can I monitor my wifi clients and put a speed limit for each one of them via my windows xp desktop pc

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a router connected to my desktop pc via ethernet cable .. this pc has no wireless card.. this router provides internet to my kids via wifi .. 
In this situation can I monitor the online activites of my kids and put a speed limit for each one from my desktop , and how ?
[QOS setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVsWF.jpg)

[WIRELESS QOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvD0A.jpg)

Comment: My router is d_link dsl 2600u , can I at least limit the speed of all wifi clients -if speed limit to each one is not possible- so it becomes , for example 90% of speed for the ethernet cable and 10% for wifi clients ?!

Comment: A Windows XP computer connected to the internet? This far past the end of support? The horror...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague on details, but the short answer is no.

Most consumer routers with default firmware can't rate limit on a per client basis or track usage per client, just in aggregate. You can investigate whether DDWRT, OPENWRT or Tomato can do this on your particular model of router but be aware that its not amateur friendly and from the level of your post I suspect you may find it difficult. If unsure, do nothing, as a bad firmware flash will turn your router into a paperweight.

Comment: My router is d_link dsl 2600u , can I at least limit the speed of all wifi clients  -if speed limit to each one is not possible- so it becomes  , for example 90% of speed for the ethernet cable and 10% for wifi clients ?!

Comment: The manual is very very basic, impossible to say if its possible. Check for a page with QoS or quality of service and post a screenshot if there is one.

Comment: I just edited my question adding 2 screenshots .. I hope this will help answering my question .. Thanks ..

Comment: It appears it cant do it, you'll need better equipment.